# model events are not working in Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am using `Marionette.js` for making an Application.

model event was not triggering If I change `Attribute` value in `view.initialize` function just like in the following way.

```
var ChartsView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
   initialize:function(){
      this.model.set({"currentJson":""},{silent:true});
      this.model.set({"currentJson":"test"});
   },
   modelEvents:{
    "change:currentJson":"settingOtherAttributesInSameModel"
  },
  settingOtherAttributesInSameModel:function(){
     console.log("This is Testing");
  }
});
```

while instance creation time, I am passing the model object just like in the following way.

```
chartsViewObj=new ChartsView({el:$('#plannerTablePlace'),model:chartsModelObj});
```

I don't know, why `model event` was not working.

I didn't find,where I wrong.

can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `delegateEvents` function that bind the view events is called after the `initialize` function. Thus when you do this :

```
initialize:function(){
  this.model.set({"currentJson":""},{silent:true});
  this.model.set({"currentJson":"test"});
}
```

The attribute is set and the `change` event is triggered but the view events are not yet bound.

---

So if you want the events to be triggered, do like this :

```
chartsViewObj=new ChartsView({el:$('#plannerTablePlace'),model:chartsModelObj});

chartsModelObj.set({"currentJson":""},{silent:true}); // this will not trigger the event because of 'silent:true'
chartsModelObj.set({"currentJson":"test"});
```